Python ThreadingHTTPServer is not actually multithreaded
I'm tryin to create a multithreaded HTTP server in Python 3.10 using ThreadingHTTPServer. However, ThreadingHTTPServer doesn't seem to be working multithreadedly - each GET request waits for the previous one to finish. To simulate a long-running operation, I'm using time.sleep() and then making two simultaneous GET requests. Based on the timestamps, I can see that the second GET request waits for the first one to complete.
How can I fix this?
from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        start = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        wait_time = random.randint(2, 6)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        response = f"{start}: wait {wait_time}"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response.encode('utf-8'))

def start_http_server():
    httpd = ThreadingHTTPServer( ("", 8080), Handler)
    httpd.serve_forever()


It turns out that all it takes is to swap the order of executing the long-running operation and sending the headers. If the headers are sent first and then the long-running operation is started, everything happens multithreadedly.

I did not find it necessary to change the order of anything and two concurrent requests are running concurrently, at least on Python 3.12. By the way, you should always post a [mre]. You are missing required import statements and the call to start_http_server. I should be able to copy and paste the code with no changes and it runs and reproduces your issue.
